# В Shiny-приложение получить заголовки загружаемой таблицы

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

Хочу получить заголовки таблицы, и вставить их в checkbox, для дальнейшей сортировки и отбора нужных столбцов. Таблицу получаю путем загрузки файла:

Server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
server <- function(input, output) {

  names <- reactive({ read_excel(input$file1$name, sheet = 1,
                      range = "A1:P1", col_names = TRUE)
                    })
}
```

**Ui.R**

```
 library(shiny)
 library(shinythemes)
 ui <- fluidPage(

  theme=shinytheme("readable"),

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("App_1"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(


      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose File",
                multiple = FALSE),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),


      checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:", names(names) )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `renderUI`.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$file1)) return(NULL)
    read_excel(input$file1$name, sheet = 1, range = "A1:P1", col_names = TRUE)
  })

  col_names <- reactive({
    colnames(data())
  })

  output$vars <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(data())) return(NULL)
    tagList(
      checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:", col_names())
    )
  })

  output$tbl <- renderDataTable({
    if (is.null(data())) return(NULL)
    if (length(input$show_vars) == 0L)
      return(data())
    else
      return(select(data(), one_of(input$show_vars)))
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("App_1"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose File", multiple = FALSE),
      tags$hr(),
      uiOutput("vars")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("tbl")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```